# Amazon Native Shopping Ads (Search Ads) in React

Tags: reactjs, amazon-advertising-api

https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/welcome/getstarted_fifth

Is it possible to introduce Amazon Native Shopping Ads' 「Search Ads 」 into the React project?

I attempted trial and error, but I do not think that it is probably going well with global variable issues.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I did it.

If your Native Shopping Ads code looks like this:

```
<div id="amzn-assoc-ad-xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"></div><script async src="//z-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/onejs?MarketPlace=US&adInstanceId=xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"></script>
```

In your component,

```
componentDidMount () {
    const script = document.createElement("script");

    script.src = "//z-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/onejs?MarketPlace=US&adInstanceId=xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
    script.async = true;

    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

In your JSX

```
<div id="amzn-assoc-ad-xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"> </div>
```

Comment: Thanks!
I'd like to dynamically change the search keyword of "Search Ads" by page.

Do you know how to do it What?

Comment: Native Shopping Ads code has been changed to

<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script></script>

Can you update the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it works very well with this logic but I made a better version out of it.

In your React Hook

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script')
    script.text = `amzn_assoc_ad_type = "banner"; amzn_assoc_marketplace = "amazon"; amzn_assoc_region = "US"; amzn_assoc_placement =
    "assoc_banner_placement_default"; .................`

    const script2 = document.createElement('script')
    script2.src = '//z-na.amazon-adsystem.com............'
    script2.async = false

    const amazonAdd = document.querySelector('#amzn_assoc_ad_div_assoc_banner_placement_default_0')
    if (amazonAdd) {
      amazonAdd.appendChild(script)
      amazonAdd.appendChild(script2)
    }
  }, [])
```

In your JSX

```
<div id="amzn_assoc_ad_div_assoc_banner_placement_default_0" />
```

You need to use the exact same id than amazon uses. Take a look in your DOM to see how this amazon script append a div in your DOM, get its id and use the same in your JSX div